# LDAP and group filter

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to setup RhodeCode as well as other services to work with LDAP (OpenLDAP v3) and everything goes fine except one thing, my structure looks like this:

```
dc=domain,dc=com  
ou=Groups | ou=People  
hgusers   | test1  
sshusers  | test2  
others
```

These are examples via ldapsearch

```
dn: cn=sshusers,ou=Group,dc=domain,dc=com  
objectClass: top  
objectClass: posixGroup  
cn: sshusers  
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fXg=  
gidNumber: 14567  
memberUid: test1  


dn: uid=test1,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com  
uid: test1  
cn: Test User  
objectClass: account  
objectClass: posixAccount  
objectClass: top  
objectClass: shadowAccount  
shadowLastChange: 15472  
shadowMax: 99999  
shadowWarning: 7  
loginShell: /bin/sh  
uidNumber: 10099  
gidNumber: 10099  
homeDirectory: /home/test1  
gecos: test  
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9WDUvSWpYeU9YQjlESGxYdy9ETWFTRFhaejFVN3VLSm8=
```

Now I'm trying to create a filter for RhodeCode and other things, so it allow access for people only from hgusers group, but I have no idea how to create it. What worries me there's no memberOf attribute that I could use and don't really know how I could add it. Could anybody help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

I would use either organizationalRole or groupOfUniqueNames as the group class, and set respectively roleOccupant or uniqueMember to the DN of the user who is in the group. Then you just search that subtree for groups with the user DN in that attribute. UID will also work, but it has referential integrity problems that you can solve if you use a DN-valued attribute and the 'refint' overlay, whcih you really must.

Answer (score 0):

Go about it the other way. Don't try to assign the groups to the user, but rather create groups that are a list of users.

If you create a groupOfUniqueNames with a series of uniqueMember attributes, each being the DN of one of your users, you won't see that when you dump the attributes if your users.

But a simple search for:
    "uniqueMember=*dn-of-user*”
Will give you every group which has the user as a member.